# How to forward from one action to another without action class in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

I am new to struts 2. I am moving my struts 1 code to struts 2. Please see below action.

```
<action name ="formName" path="/abc.xyz.action" scope="request" type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction" parameter="/pqr.rst.do">
</action>
```

So basically JSP calls the action abc.xyz.action.do and without going to any action class (JAVA class) it forwards this action to  pqr.rst.do

How can i migrate this action mapping in struts 2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the usefulness or meaning of that thing ?

Comment: Actually there are some legacy code which is involved. So we have to implement the action this way only. Secondly if I use result type as "redirect" then I am not getting URL parameters e.g http://abc.com?name="abc" . I am not getting value abc in "pqr.rst"'s action

Comment: Maybe this link helps you http://www.infoq.com/articles/migrating-struts-2-part2.

Answer (score 0):

To forward:

```
<action name="formName" >
    <result type="redirect">/pqr.rst.do</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Actually there are some legacy code which is involved. So we have to implement the action this way only. Secondly if I use result type as "redirect" then I am not getting URL parameters e.g abc.com?name="abc"; . I am not getting value abc in "pqr.rst"'s action